# AngularJs ui-chart date axis not working

Tags: angularjs, jqplot

I am using the ui-chart directive for jqplot to show a line chart in my angularjs application. But the date xaxis is not showing. The chart data is from an api call. I am setting the chart data as below.

```
$scope.chartData = [];
angular.forEach(response, function (price, key) {
    this.push([price.Sale_Date, price.Price]);
}, $scope.chartData);
```

The HTML for the chart

```
<div ui-chart="data" chart-options="chartOptions"></div>
```

However, when I set the values manually it works.

```
$scope.chartData = [[['2008-12-08 4:00PM', 4], ['2008-12-09 4:00PM', 6.5]]];
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's respinse? Can you `console.log`?

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/mymvpfL6/

Comment: @Michelem Sorry there was a typo in the header. I meant date xaxis. Reponse is from a web api that returns dates and prices. The data is returned correctly. Just that the chart doesn't render the xaxis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution in case its of use to anyone. The issue was a combination of the array & date format.

```
var prices = [];
angular.forEach(response, function (price, key) {
    this.push([new Date(price.Sale_Date), price.Price]);
}, prices);
$scope.chartData = [prices];
```